# Raspberry Pi minimum sleep time

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, sleep, ps2

I managed to connect an old PS/2 keyboard to the GPIO pins of my Raspberry Pi. I do get correct data from the keyboard which means when I press 'A' on the keyboard I get 'A' in my C code. The big issue I've got now is that I can't put a sleep delay into my code because even `usleep(1)` is taking too much time so I don't get correct data or even any data anymore. I tried `nanosleep` too but for some reason this got totally ignored by my code. Is there any agreeable way to put in a short delay? Without a delay my code is consuming 99% of CPU time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's really no good way to do this. When you call sleep, a system call is made and the OS goes off and runs other programs while you sleep. But the OS scheduler has a minimum timeslice it will do that on, and that's on the order of milliseconds, not microseconds. As a result, very small sleeps will tend to either not happen at all or take far too long, which is what you're seeing.

You have two realistic options: Write a kernel module that won't suffer under the same scheduling constraints, or use an offboard processor, such as a cheap 8-bit MCU to do the decoding, sending the results back via a serial port. I would recommend the latter.